# I install java7 and java8 using Jenv. Then, run "jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.121", I get error saying that it's not installed

Tags: java, macos, installation, jenv

On my Mac-pro OS-X Yosemite, I install java7 and java8 using Jenv.

```
$ brew cask install java8

$ brew cask install java7
```

Then execute the "jenv add" commands as followed for each java:

```
$ sudo jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

> oracle64-1.7.0.80 added

I can see both at /Users/xxxxx/.jenv/versions

```
$ ls -lrt
```

> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  64 Feb  1 13:42 oracle64-1.8.0.121 ->
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  63 Feb  1 13:49 oracle64-1.7.0.80 ->
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home

But when I try to set java8 as global, it says that java8 is not installed.

```
$ jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.121
```

> jenv: version `oracle64-1.8.0.121' not installed

Did I miss anything here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: my experience with trying to have dual jvms in OS X is : don't do it. Unless there is an express need, don't do it. In the apple java dev list there are still people who can help you with this

Comment: In my case, jenv was complaining about missing version '13'. I fixed this by editing `~/.jenv/version` where I replaced '13' with the most recent version that I added to jenv before, this was '13.0.1'.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I solved this by edited the file /Users/[YourName]/.java-version myself. For example, I entered oracle64-1.8.0.121 as the first line in this file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I discovered that jenv creates soft links for various 'versions' it controls, but it wouldn't create the soft link without the .0.  So if something wants java 11, and my team somehow uses 11 as the jenv version, I wouldn't have 11... I would have 11.0

I resolved this by adding a soft link for the number I needed under:
~/Users/<my_home>/.jenv/versions

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps

```
depoddar-mac:inbound depoddar$ jenv versions
* system (set by /Users/depoddar/.jenv/version)
  1.7
  1.7.0.80
  1.8
  1.8.0.333
  11.0
  11.0.15
  17.0
  17.0.3
  openjdk64-11.0.15
  openjdk64-17.0.3
  oracle64-1.7.0.80
  oracle64-1.8.0.333
depoddar-mac:inbound depoddar$ jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.333
depoddar-mac:inbound depoddar$ jenv version
oracle64-1.8.0.333 (set by /Users/depoddar/.jenv/version)
depoddar-mac:inbound depoddar$ jenv versions
  system
  1.7
  1.7.0.80
  1.8
  1.8.0.333
  11.0
  11.0.15
  17.0
  17.0.3
  openjdk64-11.0.15
  openjdk64-17.0.3
  oracle64-1.7.0.80
* oracle64-1.8.0.333 (set by /Users/depoddar/.jenv/version)
```